# Recommendation on Quine's text

Tags: logic, book-recommendation

I'm planning to study logic seriously and I think Quine's style is fine to me so i'm going to read his book.

There are two famous books by him. Namely, "Methods of logic" and "Mathematical logic".

I don't know which fits to me. This is my first time learning logic seriously. Which of those are suitable to a first-learner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather strongly recommend you to take a look at Peter Smith's [Teach Yourself Logic Guide](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic12-0a.pdf) first. As the same suggests, this is a guide for students that want to learn serious logic by themselves, mostly Philosophy or Mathematics students that had just take some very elementary logic courses during their classes.

Answer (score 1):

There are many modern ML textbook (see PS' Guide in the answer above).

**If** you are really interested into Quine's approach to logic, I think that *Methods of Logic* (4th ed 1982) is more like a textbook (possibly to be supplemented with Warren Goldfarb, *Deductive Logic* (2003)), while *Mathematical logic* (2nd ed 1981) is more devoted to a "modernization" of W&R, *Principia Mathematica*.

Answer (score 1):

I  strongly advice against Quines book as introduction of logic. (also against his notation btw)

They are just no good. (to much on bi valued logic , not enough on formal reasoning)

I would suggest
"language proof and logic" by Barwise cs or (maybe bit to expensive)

"techniques of formal reasoning, second  Edition " by Kalish cs (get it second hand for almost nil)

"logic" by Tomassi (I learned logic from it )

but read Paul smiths advice first

alther option do the free cousera course on logic :)

Good luck

Comment: "I strongly advice against Quines book as introduction of logic. (also against his notation btw)" - me too :)